# Ionic 3 : How to add the app to the share menu?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am looking to receive the URL and other content from pages visited in the browser. How can I achieve this with Ionic 3? It would consist of clicking the share button in the browser, choosing my app, and then being able to save the data to my app.

This is what it looks like after you click on your app in the share menu. (a different app) but I want to create an interface like this which sends data to the user:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean working with the [in app browser](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) to pass data back to the app ?

Comment: @gerdi i was talking about the regular browser, for example if someone was using the google chrome app or safari etc.